# Ignoring Vulnerabilities found by npm audit in devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

Can I safely ignore vulnerabilities found by npm audit in devDependencies? What are the consequences of ignoring them on the production build?

Comment: There isn't a single answer to this. What's the vulnerability? Does your use expose your package to that? Is it going to be part of the production output?

Comment: I am not sure actually. Here are some examples (there are numerous of them): Package: ssri, Dependency: uglifyjs-webpack-plugin,
Package: serialize-javascript, Dependency: copy-webpack-plugin,
Package: xmlhttprequest-ssl, Dependency: karma,
Package: yargs-parser, Dependency: webpack,
Package: web3, Dependency: web3,
Package: underscore, Dependency: web3